# Bash - Batch Replace Character At Certain Position

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have thousands of text-based files, and I want to change the second character of every line of each of these files to "9". What is the quickest way to make this happen?

Comment: see: https://www.unix.com/emergency-unix-and-linux-support/194687-replace-nth-position-character-all-lines-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i.bak 's/^\(.\)./\19/1' <file>` would be the heart of this.

This means use the Stream EDitor (`sed`) to Substitute (`s/`) beginning of line (`^`) followed by one character (`.`) which we are going to set aside for later backreference (`\(\)`) and another character (second `.`) with (`/`) the first character we set aside (`\1`) followed by the literal 9, first instance per line (`/1`). The `-i.bak` does In-place change with backup file; you'll end up with thousands of `*.bak` files in case something goes wrong (recommended to do this, I do not guarantee my work).

Depending on where your files are, you can either replace `<file>` with a pattern (e.g. `*.txt` or `*/*.txt`) if they are all in the same directory or the directory hierarchy is simple, or if they are strewn all over a deep directory hierarchy, use `find`, e.g., `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/^\(.\)./\19/1'`

Answer (score 2):

`sed 's/./9/2' file`

Replace the second occurence of any character in each line with 9.

Probably requires GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

It makes changes directly in the original files

```
sed -i 's/^\(.\{1\}\)./\19/' *.txt
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer, otherwise it doesn't add value and marked as a low quality answer.

Comment: @ShaneK Without using **-i** it does not makes any changes in the original files.